# git format-patch not working from bash script

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

I have a list of commits available in **commits.txt** file and i need to prepare a list of patches of these commits so as to apply them later to my branch. I have written below bash script to do so :-

```
#!/tools/bin/bash

echo "Enter input file name"
read FILENAME

echo "Enter log file name"
read LOGNAME 

while read line;
do 
    git show -- $line > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
    then
        git format-patch -- $line -1
    else
        echo "NOT FOUND, Log commit ID"
        $line >> $LOGNAME
    fi
done < $FILENAME
```

I enter input file name as "commits.txt" and log file name as "mylog.txt".
I'm not getting the *.patch files out of these list of commits.
Any clue, whats going wrong?

Thanks,
Prasanna NAVARATNA

Comment: Rather than laboriously prompt the user for the file names, just pass them as arguments: `script commits.txt mylog.txt`. Inside the script, `FILENAME=$1 LOGNAME=$2`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least these issues:

1. For `git show`, put `--` *after* the `$line`, because the commit ID is a revision.
2. For `git format-patch`, the `-1` needs to be before the `--` (which is actually unnecessary).
3. For the log, try `echo $line >>$LOGNAME`, for otherwise it will try to run a program with the name of your commit ID.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, `git cherry-pick $(tr '\n' ' ' commits.txt)` may already do it: apply all the listed commits to the current branch.

Comment: If i don't put -- after "git show" or "git format-patch", it is throwing error and suggesting to put --
Error : Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
Even if i use "echo $line >>$LOGNAME" then also no use.
I haven't checked your cherry-pick command because i'm new to git and don't exactly know which branch, where commits are etc.
But i'll give a try once i figure out and will let you know. Thanks.
Right now, i achieved the same results with short'n'sweet **C** code!

Comment: As I said, `git show` with `--`, yes, but *after* the `$line`: `git show $line --`